# Node js SOAP library trouble with the word DateAdvance

Tags: node.js, soap

I am using this library node js https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap . When I try to give the client args, if the parameter is DateAdvance: '"gives the following error:

```
Error: soap: Client: Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (1, 467). ---> Input string was not in a correct format
```

This is part of the code

```
var soap = require ('soap');
   var url = 'https://elstestserver.endicia.com/LabelService/EwsLabelService.asmx?wsdl';
   var args = {LabelRequest: {DateAdvance: ""}};
   soap.createClient (url, function (err, client) {
       client.MyFunction (args, function (err, result) {
           console.log (result);
       });
   });
```

It is only with the word DateAdvance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im a idiot, in the documentation of the SOAP service say that field is integer, i need to put that without double quote. Sorry for the troubles.

```
var args = {LabelRequest: {DateAdvance: 0}};
```